# Como remover e adicionar um determinado TD

Tags: javascript, html, table

Dentro cada`tr` há vários `buttons` (add e remover) e seus respectivos `td`(s), como saber que determinado `tr` eu devo eliminar se eu clicar em um dos buttons de add ou rem? Também queria adicionar um novo `tr` de classe pacientes logo abaixo do outro tr?
Segue o jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nn40pty3/

```
            <table id="tabela-1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>Peso(kg)</th>
                    <th>Altura(m)</th>
                    <th>IMC</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="paciente">
                    <td class="info-nome" id="nome-1">Leonardo</td>
                    <td class="info-peso" id="peso-1">57</td>
                    <td class="info-altura" id="altura-1">1.67</td>
                    <td class="info-imc" id="imc-1"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="paciente">
                    <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
                    <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
                    <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
                    <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="paciente">
                    <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
                    <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
                    <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
                    <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>                        
                </tr>
                <tr class="paciente">
                    <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
                    <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
                    <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
                    <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
                    <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>                        
                </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: não entendi? O que você precisa adicionar ou remover?

Comment: se eu clicar no botão remover, deve-se remover o TR que foi clicado (remove-lo complemente); se eu clicar no botão de adicionar, adiciona um novo TR

Comment: Porque é que ambos os button têm classe `btnadd`? posso mudar um deles para `btnremove`?

Comment: pode, é que copy/paste e esqueci de mudar os valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com dados via prompt, dê uma olhada e adapte conforme sua necessidade. Lembrando o conselho do Sergio sobre a semântica.

```js
window.onload = function() {

    var acaoBotao = function() {
        var campo = this;
      
        if (campo.value == "+") {
            // pega os elementos pais, td, tr
            var tr = campo.parentNode.parentNode;
          
            // inputs, não estou validando
            var nome = prompt("Informe seu nome: ");
            var peso = prompt("Informe seu peso: ");
            var altura = prompt("Informe sua altura: ");
          
            // clona o tr atual com seus filhos (true)
            var novoTr = tr.cloneNode(true);
            novoTr.getElementsByClassName('info-nome')[0].innerHTML = nome;
            novoTr.getElementsByClassName('info-peso')[0].innerHTML = peso;
            novoTr.getElementsByClassName('info-altura')[0].innerHTML = altura;

            var botoesNovos = novoTr.getElementsByClassName('btnadd');
            for(var i=0;i<botoesNovos.length;i++){
                 botoesNovos[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao, false);
            }
            // sobe no pai (table) e adiciona a nova linha
            tr.parentNode.appendChild(novoTr);          
        } else if (campo.value == "-") {
            var tr = campo.parentNode.parentNode;
            // remove o tr selecionado
            tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
        }
    };

    var botoes = document.getElementsByClassName("btnadd");
    // adiciona o event nos botoes conforme a classe
    for(var i=0;i<botoes.length;i++){
        botoes[i].addEventListener('click', acaoBotao, false);
    }
}
```

```css
.btnadd{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tabela-1">
    <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Peso(kg)</th>
        <th>Altura(m)</th>
        <th>IMC</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paciente">
        <td class="info-nome" id="nome-1">Leonardo</td>
        <td class="info-peso" id="peso-1">57</td>
        <td class="info-altura" id="altura-1">1.67</td>
        <td class="info-imc" id="imc-1"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paciente">
        <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
        <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
        <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
        <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="paciente">
        <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
        <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
        <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
        <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>                        
    </tr>
    <tr class="paciente">
        <td class="info-nome" id="nome-2">Paulo</td>
        <td class="info-peso" id="peso-2">100</td>
        <td class="info-altura" id="altura-2">2.00</td>
        <td class="info-imc" id="imc-2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="+" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="btnadd" value="-" /></td>                        
    </tr>
    
</table>
```

Comment: @Sergio o `event` não fica sempre implicito? sempre vou ter o `MouseClick` ou fala por ser uma boa prática?

Comment: De fato, vou corrigir

Comment: Obrigado como sempre :)

Answer (score 2):

Muda as classes dos botões que apagam para algo diferente de `btnadd`. Assim fica mais lógico/semântico o que o código faz.

Precisas de uma função que te dê o elemento `tr` mais próximo para poderes cloná-lo ou apagá-lo. Poderia ser assim:

```
function paiTr(el) {
    var tr = el;
    while (tr.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') tr = tr.parentNode;
    return tr;
}
```

e depois precisas de um oscultador de eventos que detete se carregaste num `input[type=button]` para fazeres o que queres. Pode ser assim:

```
document.getElementById('tabela-1').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var btn = e.target.type == 'button' && e.target;
    if (!btn) return;
    if (btn.classList.contains('btnadd')) {
        var tr = paiTr(btn).cloneNode(true);
        this.appendChild(tr);
    } else {
        var tr = paiTr(btn);
        tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    }
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y1qtsbwh/1/

Comment: está a dar erro nos tr já criados quando tento remover, `Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.` utilizando o `tr.remove()` funciona perfeitamente

Comment: @MaiconCarraro interessante esse erro. Nõ faz muito sentido pois `this` é o elemento `table`... Fiz de outra maneira e vou investigar. Obrigado!

Comment: Sim, eu até dei um console.log no `this` e aparentemente era pra funcionar, o mais estranho é funcionar para os novos e não nos antigos.

Comment: Algum motivo por preferir `removeChild` ao invés do `remove`?

Comment: @MaiconCarraro é porque o `.remove()` não funciona no IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

Comment: Irei corrigir isso no meu então :)